# Can't load Image into JTextArea using Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextarea

I am using `JFileChooser` to load image from the desktop into `JTextArea` but when I load image from PC, the software hangs.

Here is the code of `OpenActionPerformed` method of the file chooser.

```
private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if (returnVal == fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {
      // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
      textarea.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A JTextArea is for text not for images.

If you want to display an image then add an `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel` and add the label to the `JFrame`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information on reading images and displaying Icons.

Comment: But I am using Netbeans. There is no option for that

Comment: @Vipul.Johri First, I'd stop using netbeans form editor and start hand coding your UIs, it'll give a better appreciation for the API and second, yes it does